# SQLite Exception Data insertion issue for columns

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Here is my code for the dbHelper class:

```
package com.example.emp_management;


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, dbName, null, 1);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
static final String dbName="EmployeeManagementSystem";
static final String Login_Table="Login_Authentication";
static final String colID="ID";
static  final String colUsername="Username";
static final String colPassword="Passwrod";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
//db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + Login_Table+ "(" +
    //       colID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        //  colUsername + "TEXT NOT NULL," +
          // colPassword + "TEXT NOT NULL);"                    
            //);
//db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+Login_Table+" ("+colID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"+
    //    colUsername+ " TEXT ,"+ colPassword + "TEXT");
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + Login_Table + "(colID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, colUsername TEXT NOT NULL,colPassword TEXT NOT NULL);");
Log.w("Come aww man", "Database Table Created!!");


}
    @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "Login_Authentication");
onCreate(db);
}
public void insert_new_user(String username,String password)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(DatabaseHelper.colUsername,username);
    cv.put(DatabaseHelper.colPassword,password);
    db.insert(Login_Table, null, cv);
    db.close();
    }
}
```

Here is the code am using to add new employee into the table i have created:

```
 package com.example.emp_management;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Adding_Employee extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle aglakaam) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(aglakaam);

    setContentView(R.layout.add_employee);
    final EditText new_user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText new_pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final Button create_acc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.creat_acc);

    create_acc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DatabaseHelper accessing_db = new DatabaseHelper(Adding_Employee.this);
        accessing_db.insert_new_user(new_user.getText().toString(), new_pass.getText().toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New User Has Been Created!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
}


}
```

And here is my logcat:

```
02-20 02:42:26.491: E/Database(384): Error inserting Passwrod=1234 Username=sjdf
02-20 02:42:26.491: E/Database(384): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table     Login_Authentication has no column named Passwrod: , while compiling: INSERT INTO Login_Authentication(Passwrod, Username) VALUES(?, ?);
02-20 02:42:26.491: E/Database(384):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
```

Something wierd here to me here is that the column of username exists. Why is it only showing exception for password and not username and even when password column exists why is the exception thrown here. Kindly help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating columns with the names colPassword , colUsername , and colID

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + Login_Table + "(colID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, colUsername TEXT NOT NULL,colPassword TEXT NOT NULL);");
```

and then trying to access them using

```
static final String colID="ID";
static  final String colUsername="Username";
static final String colPassword="Passwrod";
```

Since Passwrod != colPassword .. of course you won't be able to find that column.

Try something like this to ensure you are using the same names for columns when creating the table along with accessing it.
You'll need to increase your DB version in order for the changes to show.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + Login_Table + "(" + colID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + colUsername + " TEXT NOT NULL," + colPassword + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
```

Comment: its giving the same exception sir!

Comment: @Alfred Did you increase the DB version? super(context, dbName, null, 2);

Comment: oh yea i forgot that i have the increase the version by 1 everytime i change. My application is now exiting with uncaught exception and logcat says: 02-20 03:13:30.651: E/Database(625): Failure 1 (AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY) on 0x3312f0 when preparing 'CREATE TABLE Login_Authentication(IDINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, UsernameTEXT NOT NULL,PasswordTEXT NOT NULL);'.

Comment: Shouldnt have occured as it is already INTEGER in the db query!

Comment: @Alfred Sorry, there was some spacing issues on my end. I edited my answer to reflect the spaces.. see how it says "IDINTEGER" in the error? .. it should be "ID INTEGER" .. I fixed that so if you want to copy / paste + increase the DB version it should work now

Comment: as for sqlite for android its too case sensitive

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just need space after  colID , colUsername , colPassword

db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + Login_Table + "(" + colID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + colUsername + " TEXT NOT NULL," + colPassword + " TEXT NOT NULL);");

Answer (score -1):

You misspelled Password as Passwrod.  Simple typo. Also, Java doesn't do variable string interpolation, you need to use concatenation.